# Как заставить работать "DisableWhileTyping" с драйвером synaptics

Tags: linux, gnome, manjaro, xorg

На ноутбуке стоит manjaro gnome, на нем по умолчанию стоит libinput, который очень слабо настраивается(конкретно - у меня не получилось настроить скорость прокрутки по тачпаду, ни `MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE` в `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/`, ни `Option "RotationAngle" ..` в `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` не дают никакого результата), поэтому я поставил `xf86-input-synaptics`, закинул в `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` свой конфиг, все стало нормально, но не работает отключение тачпада во время ввода с клавиатуры(syndaemon с libinput'ом не работает, либо я что-то не так делаю, потому что в какой-то момент syndaemon заработал, но потом перестал).
В общем, у меня вопрос можно ли в этой ситуации заставить работать либо DisableWhileTyping с драйвером synaptics, либо как-то настроить скорость прокрутки в libinput?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, адекватного решения я не нашел, поэтому пришлось закостылить такой "однострочник":

```
TOUCHPAD_DEV_NAME="ETD2303:00 04F3:3083 Touchpad"; DISABLE_COMMAND="xinput set-prop '$TOUCHPAD_DEV_NAME' 'Synaptics Tap Action' 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"; ENABLE_COMMAND="xinput set-prop '$TOUCHPAD_DEV_NAME' 'Synaptics Tap Action' 0 3 0 0 1 3 2"; INTERVAL=0.2; PREV_SLEEP_PID=0; unbuffer libinput debug-events --show-keycodes | unbuffer -p grep --perl-regexp 'KEY_[0-9A-Z] \([0-9]+\) (pressed|released)' | while IFS='' read -r INPUT || [[ -n "$INPUT" ]]; do if [[ "$INPUT" =~ KEY_[0-9A-Z] ]]; then if [ ${PREV_SLEEP_PID} -gt 0 ]; then kill ${PREV_SLEEP_PID} &> /dev/null; fi; eval "${DISABLE_COMMAND}"; sleep ${INTERVAL} && eval "${ENABLE_COMMAND}" & PREV_SLEEP_PID=$!; fi; done
```

// то же самое в отформатированном виде:

```
TOUCHPAD_DEV_NAME="ETD2303:00 04F3:3083 Touchpad";
DISABLE_COMMAND="xinput set-prop '$TOUCHPAD_DEV_NAME' 'Synaptics Tap Action' 0 0 0 0 0 0 0";
ENABLE_COMMAND="xinput set-prop '$TOUCHPAD_DEV_NAME' 'Synaptics Tap Action' 0 3 0 0 1 3 2";
INTERVAL=0.2;
PREV_SLEEP_PID=0;
unbuffer libinput debug-events --show-keycodes | unbuffer -p grep --perl-regexp 'KEY_[0-9A-Z] \([0-9]+\) (pressed|released)' |
while IFS='' read -r INPUT || [[ -n "$INPUT" ]];
do
  if [[ "$INPUT" =~ KEY_[0-9A-Z] ]];
  then
    if [ ${PREV_SLEEP_PID} -gt 0 ];
    then
      kill ${PREV_SLEEP_PID} &> /dev/null;
    fi;
    eval "${DISABLE_COMMAND}";
    sleep ${INTERVAL} && eval "${ENABLE_COMMAND}" & PREV_SLEEP_PID=$!;
  fi;
done
```

Работает так: скрипт следит за выводом `libinput debug-events` и если замечает, что нажата клавиша(буквы и цифры), выключает тап(параметр 'Synaptics Tap Action') и ставит таймер на включение обратно.

P.S. Скрипт возможно не очень надежный, оптимальный и все такое, поэтому просьба предлагать улучшения.